# add key value pairs to jsonobject using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to just copy metadata from one json node and add it to another. My problem is

```
       ObjectNode.put("key":"value")
```

overrides the existing data, but i need to add them.

Example:

```
    {"metadata":{ "foo":1, "boo":2}} merged with {"metadata": {"ba":7}}
```

should be

```
    {"metadata":{"foo":1, "boo":2,"ba":7}}
```

Should be quite simple, but i don't get it :( 
So any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in several ways.

First, using the Jackson API; let us call `node` the node you want to modify, `newNode` the node you want to merge:

```
final ObjectNode newMetadata = (ObjectNode) newNode.get("metadata");
final ObjectNode metadata = (ObjectNode) node.get("metadata");

metadata.putAll(newMetadata);
```

Second, (sorry: self promotion) your target JSON can be used as a [JSON Merge Patch](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-json-merge-patch-02); a library I have developped, which uses Jackson (note: 2.2.x, not 1.9.x), [has support for it](https://github.com/fge/json-patch):

```
final JsonMergePatch patch = JsonMergePatch.fromJson(newNode);
node = patch.apply(node);
```

Comment: that worked fine tank you :) (tried that before but forgot to cast to ObjectNode)

Comment: still amazed by your quick and useful answer :) and you helped me with my other post too, so thanks again ^^

Comment: Just a quick note that the `ObjectNode.putAll` overwrites existing values.  From the JavaDoc: `Method for adding all properties of the given Object, overriding any existing values for those properties.`

Answer (score 1):

To add key value pair to json object you just need to take a MAP and put the key values entries in it.now you should take JSONER object. by using serialize method of jsoner you can directly add your MAP to json.

Comment: and if its nested i just put the nested object as value in the map?